# C++ Fork Join Parallelism Blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

Suppose you wish you run a section in parallel, then merge back into the main thread then back to section in parallel, and so on. Similar to the childhood game red light green light.

I've given an example of what I'm trying to do, where I'm using a conditional variable to block the threads at the start but wish to start them all in parallel but then block them at the end so they can be printed out serially. The *= operation could be a much larger operation spanning many seconds. Reusing the threads is also important. Using a task queue might be too heavy.

I need to use some kind of blocking construct that isn't just a plain busy loop, because I know how to solve this problem with busy loops.

In English:

1. Thread 1 creates 10 threads that are blocked
2. Thread 1 signals all threads to start (without blocking eachother)
3. Thread 2-11 process their exclusive memory
4. Thread 1 is waiting until 2-11 are complete (can use an atomic to count here)
5. Thread 2-11 complete, each can notify for 1 to check its condition if necessary
6. Thread 1 checks its condition and prints the array
7. Thread 1 resignals 2-11 to process again, continuing from 2

Example code (Naive adapted from example on cplusplus.com):

```
// condition_variable example
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <atomic>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;
std::atomic<int> count(0);

bool end = false;
int a[10];

void doublea (int id) {
  while(!end) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
    a[id] *= 2;
    count.fetch_add(1);
  }
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
  ready = false; // Naive

  while (count.load() < 10) sleep(1);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
  }

  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
  ready = false;
  while (count.load() < 10) sleep(1);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
  }

  end = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main () {
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    a[i] = 0;
    threads[i] = std::thread(doublea,i);
  }

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
  go();                       // go!

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is `count` atomic? why use a condition variable on one side and use a busy sleep on another?

Comment: @UmNyobe I explicitly do not want to use busy sleeping. Threads should sleep while waiting to be notified.

For your other question, count is atomic since it can be increased by multiple threads at once with some luck. Increment is a two stage process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not as trivial to implement it efficiently. Moreover, it does not make any sense unless you are learning this subject. Conditional variable is not a good choice here because it does not scale well.

I suggest you to look how mature run-time libraries implement fork-join parallelism and learn from them or use them in your app. See http://www.openmprtl.org/, http://opentbb.org/, https://www.cilkplus.org/ - all these are open-source.

OpenMP is the closest model for what you are looking for and it has the most efficient implementation of fork-join barriers. Though, it has its disadvantages because it is designed for HPC and lacks dynamic composability. TBB and Cilk work best for nested parallelism and usage in modules and libraries which can be used in context of external parallel regions.

Comment: You are correct in saying I'm attempting to learn. I've looked at both TBB and OpenMP before but OpenMP's heavy use of pragmas is off putting and TBB has a lot of boiler plate for doing simple things.

However I would gladly give them another look and use them. For actually reading my question I'll give you the answer.

Comment: You don't want to mix the front-end (usage model) and runtime library underneath. You can write your own front-end for any of these runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use barrier or condition variable to start all threads. Then thread one can wait to when all threads end their work (by join method on all threads, it is blocking) and then print in one for loop their data.

Comment: This is not a solution because the threads need to be recreated once joined.